# Changing font size with a pinch

Tags: uiwebview, nsuserdefaults

I use the following code to change the font size of a web view with a pinch:

```
- (void)changeFontSize:(FontSizeChangeType)changeType
{
    if (changeType == FontSizeChangeTypeIncrease && _currentFontSize == 160) return;
    if (changeType == FontSizeChangeTypeDecrease && _currentFontSize == 70) return;
    if (changeType != FontSizeChangeTypeNone)
    {
        _currentFontSize = (changeType == FontSizeChangeTypeIncrease) ? _currentFontSize + 5 : _currentFontSize - 5;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_currentFontSize forKey:@"fontsize"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'",
                          _currentFontSize];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

The font size changes, and that is all great. However, if you leave the web view, and then come back later, the font size is not saved. I have to pinch, and then it reverts back to the chosen font size.
At the ViewDidLoad I call this, which I thought should work:

```
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fontsize"] == nil)
    {
        _currentFontSize = 100;
    }
    else
    {
        _currentFontSize = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"fontsize"];
    }
```

It doesn't though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be setting `_currentFontSize` out of your saved defaults in `viewDidLoad`, but you also have to make that same `[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString]` call in order to make it that size change take effect - and you have to do it *after* the web view has loaded since otherwise there will be no `body` tag.

Comment: So I have to do that in viewDidLoad? Or somewhere else?

Comment: You're just asking me to repeat myself. I don't do that. Think about it. This is a different web view and a new loading of its content. The web view loads. What's going to cause the body style to have the changed font size. Nothing, unless you change it.

Comment: But is that what         _currentFontSize = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"fontsize"];
 is doing? It is the same webView file, just a different URL.

Comment: Yes, but if it's a different URL it is all new HTML so it has not yet been affected. I'm suggesting, based on what you've said so far, that you are calling `_currentFontSize = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"fontsize"];` when you _pinch_, not when you load. That is the problem.

Comment: Also, you said "leave the web view and come back". So it is _not_ the same web view.

Comment: This may just be a case of me not being articulate enough. The WebView loads. The default font size is chosen. If you pinch to increase the text size, it stays that way until you leave and open a different URL. When that new url loads, the font size isn't the one you previously chose. Instead, it reverts to the default size. It should stick with your chosen size. When you pinch, the font size jumps to whatever you had chosen before. I want the view to load with your chosen font size. That is what it isn't doing right now.

Comment: Listen to what I'm saying. What you are doing during the pinch is changing the HTML that was already loaded. That is what your JavaScript does. If you open a different URL, that is brand new HTML, so you haven't changed it, so it doesn't have the chosen font size.

Comment: What I'm telling you is that *if* this is the way you are going to set the font size for the HTML (i.e. using JavaScript to change the body tag style), *then* it has to be done freshly for every newly loaded URL, _after_ the URL loads.

Comment: Wow, OK. Sorry for being so stupid. It worked! Thanks.